# Using jQuery to update parameters of sharethis doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharethis

I've tying since last 3 days to fix ShareThis button which actually doesn't updates the parameters(e.g. title, summary, url) when the content of a div is changed.

It works fine when the window loads but once the text of the div (in my case the text is quotes and authors) are changed the sharethis parameters do not update to match the current text.

Here's my .ready() function that executes first,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
    randomQuote(); // Generates random quotes
 });
    // Setting parameters of ShareThis
    $(window).load(function(){ // Updates the sharethis quotes and author as soon as page is finished loading and quotes and authors are displayed
      stWidget.addEntry({
             "service":   "sharethis",
             "element":   document.getElementById('shareThisCustom'),
             "url":       window.location.href,
             "title":     "Quote by: " +$("#reference").text(),
             "type":      "large",
             "text":      "QuotesBits" ,
             "image":     "http://abdurrehman.pk.tn/QuotesBits/images/qoutes-bits-logo.jpg",
             "summary":   $("#quotes").text()
       });
     updateMeta(); // Updates <meta> elements
 });

    // facebook SDK
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
      appId      : '231016417299211',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.7'
     });
 };

     (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
     // End of facebook SDK
});
```

It does its job in updating sharethis parameters when the page is loaded and quote is displayed but as soon as the quote is changed, its parameters remains same.

Following function is called whenever change to a quote is made:

```js
var updateMeta = function(){
 // Setting up meta tags for social share links
 $('.meta-title').attr('content', "Quote by: " +$("#reference").text());
 $('.meta-url').attr('content', window.location.href);
 $('.meta-desc').attr('content', $("#quotes").text());

    /*
    var switchTo5x = true;
 $.ajax({  // Reloads the script whenever a quote and author is changed
     url: 'http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js',  
     dataType: 'script',  
     success: function(){  
     // Setting stLight options
     stLight.options({publisher: "4d3ed2be-9bb6-4996-bd76-c88508432041", onhover: false, doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false})  
     } 
 });  
    */
 // Again updating the parameters of sharethis
 stWidget.addEntry({
         "service":   "sharethis",
         "element":   document.getElementById('shareThisCustom'),
         "url":       window.location.href,
         "title":     "Quote by: " +$("#reference").text(),
         "type":      "large",
         "text":      "QuotesBits" ,
         "image":     "http://abdurrehman.pk.tn/QuotesBits/images/qoutes-bits-logo.jpg",
         "summary":   $("#quotes").text()
 });

stButtons.locateElements();
}
```

Now the problem is, if I reload the sharethis script, it breaks the button which means after reloading sharethis script, whenever I click on sharehtis button, nothing happens(that's why I have putted the .ajax function in comments).

Finally, here is my sharethis span element:

```html
<span class="social-image-span">
   <a class="sharethis" href="javascript:void(0);"> <img class="sharethis" src="images/icons-normal/Share-hover.png" alt="share" /> </a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);"> <img id="shareThisCustom" class="sharethis st_sharethis_large fade" src="images/icons-normal/Share.jpg" alt="share" /> </a>
</span>
```

Is there any other way around for this problem?

P.S: You can check my project live demo for better understanding at: [QuotesBits](http://abdurrehman.pk.tn/QuotesBits)

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: What does "reload the sharethis script" mean?

Comment: @bassxzero sharethis is a social sharing tool, and to integrate it to my site, I have to link the scripts to my site which sharethis provides me. Basically sharethis parameters doesn't update dynamically through meta tags in HTML, so the only way is through javascript, and in order for sharethis to load the updated content, I think I have to reload the whole script so that sharethis button again loads the updated parameters.